# Mysql: how to list all items with sorting?

Tags: mysql, database, counting, join

I would like to have a output that having top 10 reporters with all the issue they raise. For example, mandy pang can't print in jos vpn, cant rotate pdf file and so on(Mandy has raised more than 1 issue). However I can only display one record in the output table, i would like to list all. I do not know how to write the sql statement.

the output i use this sql statement

```
Select count(*)  counts, HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 AS Reportors,HD_TICKET.TITLE AS Issue
from HD_TICKET  
group by HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 
order by counts desc 
limit 10
```

Attached is the database chart.

[Database chart](http://postimg.org/image/62c07144z/)

[Output](http://postimg.org/image/sztpzerzn/)

Comment: Tickets by mandy
http://postimg.org/image/uqcr0w9ir

Comment: Without being able to see your database setup, we're kind of at a loss. If you could, I'm sure many of us would appreciate a SQLFiddle or a screenshot of your tables. While the screenshot you posted is nice, it doesn't effectively give us the information in how your table is setup. We can make guesses, but without seeing it that is all they are - guesses. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: I do not know as i am using the system KACE to run the mysql statement, it hide the version of mysql

but it display the error like this


mysql error: [1235: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'] in EXECUTE( "select * from HD_TICKET WHERE CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 IN ( Select HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 from HD_TICKET group by HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 order by count(*) desc limit 10 ) counts LIMIT 0")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to join to the counts for each reporter:

```
  SELECT hdt1.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 reporter,
         hdt1.TITLE issue 
    FROM HD_TICKET hdt1
    JOIN (
      SELECT hdti.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 reporter,
             COUNT(*) count
        FROM HD_TICKET hdti
    GROUP BY hdti.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0
    ORDER BY count
       LIMIT 10
         ) hdt2
      ON hdt2.reporter = hdt1.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0
ORDER BY hdt2.count DESC
```

Comment: That's a table alias name.

Comment: @Mong It is just an alias for the first use of HD_TICKET, to differentiate it from it's use in the subquery and JOIN.

Comment: @Mong This method will allow the use of LIMIT in the subquery.

Comment: @Mong Any problem with this solution?

Comment: @Arth it pop up error again
mysql error: [1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(*) count FROM HD_TICKET hdti GROUP BY hdti.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALU' at line 6] in EXECUTE( "SELECT hdt1.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 reporter, hdt1.TITLE issue FROM HD_TICKET hdt1 JOIN ( SELECT hdti.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 reporter COUNT(*) count FROM HD_TICKET hdti GROUP BY hdti.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 ORDER BY count LIMIT 10 ) hdt2 ON hdt2.reporter = hdt1.reporter ORDER BY hdt2.count DESC LIMIT 0")

Comment: is the problem of "group by" missing sth? @Arth

Comment: @Mong, looks like I was missing a comma after reporter, line 5 here, and you are missing the * from the COUNT(*) count, line 6.My apologies.. see update.

Comment: @Arth Another error pop up...mysql error: [1054: Unknown column 'hdt1.reporter' in 'on clause'] in EXECUTE( "SELECT hdt1.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 reporter, hdt1.TITLE issue FROM HD_TICKET hdt1 JOIN ( SELECT hdti.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 reporter, COUNT(*) count FROM HD_TICKET hdti GROUP BY hdti.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 ORDER BY count ) hdt2 ON hdt2.reporter = hdt1.reporter ORDER BY hdt2.count DESC LIMIT 0")

Comment: @Mong oops, I used an alias where I wasn't allowed..see update.

Comment: @Arth it's okay now Thanks!!!
but another problem occur
the people cannot group together, i mean the person should be listed in group,You can see the link
http://postimg.org/image/3jm9yyf7x/

Comment: @Mong Weird, they should be ordered by the counts associated with the reporter, i.e. all the same named reporters should be next to each other. Very strange that you are joining on name however, that should be an ID of some kind, any chance you could update your question with an [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce167/1)?

Comment: @Arth
Can i ask 1 more questions?
if i also want to show the counting number of each person, how should i modify the code? for example, mandy has raise up issue for 11 times, i need to add a column that count the number of issue they raise

Comment: @Mong, that's fairly basic, just append `htd2.count` to the SELECT columns.